# Styles change on page unexpectedly

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS loaded:

```
#ue_email_new{
  border:  1px solid #000000;
}
```

It is accurately displayed on a page load.

However, after clicking on inspect element (FF 17) and viewing the CSS, I see this information in the debugger:

```
element {
    border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
```

and the border changes to this strange setting on the actual page.

Where did this come from?

I checked my CSS and can not find these settings.  What exactly is the

```
element
```

tag that the debugger is referring to?

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="wr_ue_email_new">
  <input autocomplete="off" class="radius_all" name="email" id="ue_email_new" type="text" maxlength="320" />
  <p id="ue_email_lab" class="ue_lab_new">Email</p>
</div>
```

Comment: FF 17? Upgrade first...

Comment: @bwoebi -FF17 is the current 'extended support release' for enterprise. It is still fully supported and maintained. If he's on the ESR version then there is no reason for him to need to upgrade.

Comment: is this happening with just one specific element, or is it happening generally for anything that you click on?

Comment: @Spudley Ah okay, I didn't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `element` keyword is being used to indicate the inline styles for the element. Which is why it overrides the CSS set out in your style sheet.

So in the Firefox inspector the CSS:

```
element {
    border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
```

Means that your rendered html is this:

```
<input style="border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);" autocomplete="off" class="radius_all" name="email" id="ue_email_new" type="text" maxlength="320" />
```

So first check your source html to make sure you don't have any inline styles and then check that there is no JavaScript adding the inline style.

Answer (score 1):

The `element { .... }` code that you're seeing seems like it's probably Firebug reporting the inline styles on the current element. (the current version of Firefox/Firebug that I have here says `element.style {...}` rather than `element`, as does Chrome, but I would still think that this is what it is)

I suspect that what you're seeing is some Javascript event being triggered. Possibly a `mouseover` event or similar, and that event is setting the CSS border for the element.

When you use Firebug to select an element, it suspends the page's normal event handling while you find the element you want and select it. However, as soon as you select the element, the page returns to normal and events are triggered.

My guess is the event in question is being triggered immediately at this point. The Javascript code for the event is run, and the CSS border is set. This then appears to be Firebug making changes to the styles, but it isn't; it's just your event handling code doing something unexpected.

This also explains why you couldn't find the code in your CSS -- because it's in your JS code.

I would try searching you JS code for the colour in question (as @adaam says, the equivalent hex value is `#DDDDDD`, although it might also be `#DDD`).